# Convert from class based component to fonctional component

Tags: reactjs

i need help turning this particular line `this.setState({ [name]: value });`  to work in a functional component

```
handleSelectChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

<Select
    name="selectedAddress"
    value={selectedAddress}
    options={Addresses}
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
      />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a functional component this would look something like this:

```js
const MyFuncComp = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  handleSelectChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    setSelected(current => Object.assign({}, current, {[name]: value}));
  };

  return <Select
    name="selectedAddress"
    value={selectedAddress}
    options={Addresses}
    onChange={handleSelectChange}
    />;
}
```